# Merging similar pairs in a Redshift table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have my data in `Amazon Redshift` which looks as follows:

```
   Q1          Q2        Occ           Prob               Q1ID    Q2ID
fe349344    f821b6e1    1280    6.62226553857608E-7      AC.122  AC.124
f821b6e1    fe349344    1127    5.830697860918158E-7     AC.124  AC.122
fe349344    fb13cd0e    967     5.002914668596148E-7     AC.122  AC.124
1208bf29    02174133    945     4.889094479651871E-7     AC.831  AC.356
```

As we can see in the fist 2 rows, the pair values for `Q1` and `Q2` are the same. For my case here, I don't care if the same pair appears as `Q1-Q2` or `Q2-Q1`. So I would like to change this to reflect only 1 pair for every 2 pairs available. I'm having a hard time coming up with language to describe this, so here's the result that I want:

```
   Q1          Q2        Occ           Prob               Q1ID    Q2ID
fe349344    f821b6e1    2407    1.245296339949424E-6     AC.122  AC.124
fe349344    fb13cd0e    967     5.002914668596148E-7     AC.122  AC.124
1208bf29    02174133    945     4.889094479651871E-7     AC.831  AC.356
```

Here, I have collapsed the rows 1 and 2 to just row 1, and added the values for columns `Occ` and `Prob`.

**My question is: How do I achieve this using a query? I believe it requires a self join, but I'm not sure how to write on to achieve this task.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `least` and `greatest` (as you don't care if the pair appears as q1-q2 or q2-q1) to get one row per symmetric pair (if it exists) and sum the other columns.

```
select least(q1,q2) as q1, greatest(q1,q2) as q2,
sum(occ),sum(prob),least(q1id,q2id) as q1id, greatest(q1id,q2id) as q2id
from t
group by least(q1,q2), greatest(q1,q2),least(q1id,q2id), greatest(q1id,q2id)
```

If the q1id and q2id are related to columns q1 and q2 and if the corresponding values should show up in those columns, use

```
select least(q1,q2) as q1, greatest(q1,q2) as q2,
sum(occ),sum(prob),
case when least(q1,q2) = q1 then q1id else q2id end as q1id,
case when greatest(q1,q2) = q2 then q2id else q1id end as q2id
from t
group by least(q1,q2), greatest(q1,q2),
case when least(q1,q2) = q1 then q1id else q2id end,
case when greatest(q1,q2) = q2 then q2id else q1id end
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the usage of `LEAST` and `GREATEST` here, but your first query did the job. The second query is giving me incorrect results. 
I'm also amazed at the speed of your first query. I was dealing with a table containing 16+ million records, it reduced them to over 9 Million pairs. This was done in under 7 seconds, which makes me a little bit suspicious.. The results look good to the naked eye, though.

Comment: the second query should work as expected. please clarify what you mean by *the results look incorrect*.

Comment: I'm sorry! I had made a mistake in copying the query and re-writing column names. The 2nd query works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.q1 < t.q2
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.q1 > t.q2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.q1 = t1.q2 and t2.q2 = t1.q1);
```

In Redshift, I might be more inclined to do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by least(q1, q2), greatest(q1, q2)) as cnt
      from t
      ) t
where q1 < q2 or
      (q2 > q1 and cnt = 2);
```

Note:  This assumes that there are no duplicate rows for values of `q1`, `q2`.

(More inclined means:  I'm scared of doing a correlated subquery in Redshift.  It supports them grammatically but I don't know how well they work.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the `<` and `>` characters are doing here? If they're just `less than` and `greater than` symbols, how will they compare string values? I'd also like to add the `Occ` and `Prob` columns for these pairs.

Comment: @Patthebug . . . String values are compared based on the collation.  This is usually based on alphabetical ordering.